# Всплывающая ссылка после отправки данных

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Человек хочет, чтобы посетитель заполнил форму данных (имя, телефон, категория, всякая всячина) и только после того, как он форму эту отправит, ему должна открываться большая яркая ссылка на оплату. Как это можно реализовать?

p.s. нет, я не прошу готового решения, я прошу указать, в каком направлении рыть.

Comment: На каком этапе возникли сложности?

Comment: Нет этапов. Я просто не знаю, откуда начать. Хотелось бы без скриптов, конечно, но я не уверена, что так получится. А силами верстки я не знаю как. Просто условие: "после 100% отправки формы", то есть должен быть какой-то клик же, а верстка это не реализовывает вроде. Или?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация: [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples)

```
// Отправка данных
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
// Данные отправлены (ответ сервера 200)
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```